# Separate header with line in letter

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I'm using scrlttr2 and koma script to write a letter. I have a header and I want to separate the header with something like a `\hrule` from the rest of the letter. I tried `\setheadsepline{1pt}` but it has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,SN]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{scrpage2} % for setheadsepline

\setkomavar{fromname}{It's me!}

\setheadsepline{1pt}[\color{grey}]

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
    address
}

\opening{Hello}

some letter

\closing{Goodbye}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

and this is how the top of my letter looks like. After the header ("It's me!"), I'd like to have a separating line.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `scrpage2` in a `scrlttr2` document is not useful because `\opening` sets the pagestyle to `empty`.

You can use the class option `fromrule=below` to get a line below of the header:

```
\documentclass[SN,fromrule=below]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{fromrule}{\color{purple}}% change the line color
\makeatletter
\@setplength{fromrulethickness}{1pt}% change the thickness, default is 0.4pt
\makeatother
\setkomavar{fromname}{It's me!}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{My address}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{%
    address
}

\opening{Hello}

some letter

\closing{Goodbye}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]